# Multiple function call on button click synchronously with async-await not working

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to figure out how to call multiple methods with 1 button click synchronously. My first function is an AJAX call. So it's naturally not synchronous. To solve that issue I have used async-await. Async-await is waiting inside the same function, but not on the other functions that are being called.

I am using Stimulus.js to create classes, but general answer is enough for me: https://stimulusjs.org/

This is what my code looks like:

Button: onClick:

```
classA#methodA classB#methodB
```

in class A

```
async methodA(event){
  const response = await axios.post('/url', { data }, options);
  const data = await response.json();
  doSomething()
}
```

in class B

```
methodB(){
  updateThings()
}
```

So what I want to achieve is `classA#methodA classB#methodB` be called synchronously. But methodA is not waiting for methodB even though methodA is not compete. And even when I am using async await on methodA.

Any idea on how I can solve this issue?

Creating a wrapper method and calling them doesn't seem possible because of the way Stimulus.js works.

Answer (score 1):

In your button click, you should have something like that:

```
async () => {
    await methodA();
    await methodB();
}
```

And also, the both methods should have the `async` mark:

```
async methodA(event){
  const response = await axios.post('/url', { data }, options);
  const data = await response.json();
  doSomething()
}

async methodB(){
  updateThings()
}
```

As your methodA is async, the main call to this method by default won't wait it to finish before executing the next lines. So you should explicitly say `await methodA()`.

Check it out:
[Understanding async await in javascript](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-async-await-in-javascript-1d81bb079b2c)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but because of Stimulus.js using a wrapper method is not an option.